# regex: match lines that doesn't end with '}' and has match one of three words

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have this text:

```
        NBA:red this line has a tab and ends with a curly braces}
    some random text qwertyuiop
    NBA:green this line must match
            NBA:red this line has a tab and must match
      NBA:response this line has spaces and must match
            NBA:blue this line has a tab and ends with a curly braces}
    some random text qwertyuiop
      NBA:blue this line has spaces at the begining and ends with curly braces}
    random text qwertyuiop
    this line must not match}
            this line must not match }
```

I want to match the lines that contains 'NBA:' following by the word 'red' or 'green' or 'blue', and also that doesn't end with a curly braces'}', this command match only 'NBA:' and one of the three words:

```
$ egrep 'NBA:(red|green|blue)' myfile.txt
        NBA:red this line has a tab and ends with a curly braces}
    NBA:green this line must match
            NBA:red this line has a tab and must match
            NBA:blue this line has a tab and ends with a curly braces}
      NBA:blue this line has spaces at the begining and ends with curly braces}
```

But I don't know how to match the lines that doesn't end with '}':
I tried this but it doesn't work:

`egrep 'NBA:(red|green|blue)*[^}]$' myfile.txt`

But this works:

```
egrep 'NBA:(red|green|blue)' lorem.txt | egrep '[^}]$'
    NBA:green this line must match
            NBA:red this line has a tab and must match
```

I want to do it in just one command

Comment: Re "I want to do it in just one command", I often amused by this attitude. Are you getting charged money per command you execute? :-) The beauty of UNIX pipelines is the fact that you *can* string together many filters into a pipeline to achieve what you need.

Comment: I just want to learn how to do it :-), I have no problems with the number of commands and pipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just one character off. This should work fine:

```
egrep 'NBA:(red|green|blue).*[^}]$'
#                          ^
#                   Note this bit.
```

`*` doesn't mean the same thing in regex that it does in glob patterns. It means zero-or-more of the preceding item (a preceding item in this answer being `.`, any character).

Comment: thanks!!! I just start learning regex and didn't know that, I edited the question btw

Comment: Just found this, I will leave it here just in case someone else is struggling with this:    In regular expressions, the asterisk is a metacharacter for zero or more instances of the preceding character.
    Without regular expressions, the asterisk is a wildcard, for zero or more instances of any character.